# How to Run TestNG using Linux Shell file

Tags: java, linux, shell, selenium, testng

I am using following working command for Windows batch file.

```
set projectLocation=E:\APPIUM\CXMFunctionalTest\LinuxAPITest
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml
pause
```

How i can convert this into `Linux Shell Script`? So i can run it in Linux machine.

Comment: That depends a bit on your *Nix environment, how you plan to run it, etc, but what did you try so far and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: It's a bit like asking "How can I convert this Java code into Haskell code" ? The only generic recipe is quite disappointing since it's "reverse-engineer the original code, then code the resulting algorithm in the target language".

Comment: Anyway I think these two commands should work just fine : `cd /your/project/path; java -cp "./bin:./lib/*" org.testng.TestNG ./testng.xml` (where `/your/project/path` should be the unix path equivalent to `E:\APPMIUM\CXMFunctionalTest\LinuxAPITest`)

Comment: *IX systems don't have drive letters, the path separator is a forward slash, it's conventional to use snake case in shell commands and directory/file names, and environment variables use `${}` rather than the `%` character, so your commands will look something like `project_location=/home/yourname/projects/appium/cxm_functional_test/api_test` and `cd ${project_location}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/[[youruser]]/APPIUM;
java org.testng.TestNG /home/[[youruser]]/APPIUM/testng.xml;
```

This should be sufficient, considering that `[[youruser]]` is your users home folder, and the `APPIUM` folder is placed directly inside it. Then you can put this in a file called `runappium.sh`, and run it with the command `sh appium.sh` or mark it executable and run it directly.